# React-Native Base 64 Data to FileSystem issue

Tags: php, react-native, base64, filesystems

I have a very simple PHP file that returns my image as BASE64 data

```
<?php
require_once 'database_connections.php'; 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->id);
$page = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->page);

$path = "../../images/" . $id . '/' . $page . '.jpg';

$imagedata = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);   

echo($base64);
```

?>

In my react app, I am fetching this data like below

```
export const getImage = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      url,
      {
        id: '11bb2c1b-c262-4171-b614-d8af46898efb',
        page: '001',
      }
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
    console.error(error.message);
  }
};
```

my base64  response like below:

```
/9j/2wCEAAEBAQEBAQEBAQECAQEBAgICAQECAgICAgICAgIDAgMDAw...
```

and finally my FileSystem code is like below:

```
const image = await getImage();
  const filename = FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'imagetest.jpg';
  await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(filename, image, {
    encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
  });
```

I'm not getting any error but my file is not being saved as I try. I have been working on this for hours but didn't solve my issue.

any advice would be appreciated!

Edit: I can show the base64 image in an Image component.

Comment: Can you show your base64 image into `Image` from `react-native`?

Comment: @VasylNahuliak thanks for your comment. Yes, I have just tried it and I can show the image into an Image component.

Answer (score 1):

you wont be able to see your saved image file in FileSystem.documentDirectory , you need to

```
FileSystem.readDirectoryAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory).then(data => {
data.forEach(filename_ => {
  console.log("=cached image==***===" + filename_)
})
```

to check if it is there. FileSystem.documentDirectory is only "pragmatically accessible"